# How to trigger an action after model and related m2m (groups) fields are saved?

Tags: python, django, m2m

How to do something after a Django user model save, including related changes to m2m fields like `django.contrib.auth.models.Group`?

## Situation

I have a custom Django user model and want to trigger some actions after a user instance is - with related changes such as m2m group memberships - successfully saved to the database. 
The use case here is a Wagtail CMS where I create `ProfilePage`s for each user instance. Depending of the group memberships of the user instance, I need to do something.

## Problem

In a custom model `save()` method, I'm not able to reference the changed group memberships, as m2m's are saved after the saving of the user instance. Even if running my custom function after the `super().save()` call, new group memberships are not yet available. 
But I need to get the new group memberships in order to do something depending of the new groups for that user.

## What I've tried

### [✘] Custom model `save()`

```py
# file: users/models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    do_something()
```

### [✘] Signal post_save

As the above simple save() method did not do the trick, I tried the `post_save` signal of the user model:

```py
# file users/signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def handle_profilepage(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    action = 'created' if created else 'updated'
    do_something()
```

... but even here I always get the "old" values from the group membership back.

### [✔] Signal: m2m_changed

I learnt that there is a `m2m_changed` signal with which I could monitor changes of the `Users.groups(.through)` table.

My following implementation did what I need:

```py
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=User.groups.through)
def user_groups_changed_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    USER_GROUPS = instance.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
    if set(USER_GROUPS) & set(settings.PROFILE_GROUPS):
        do_something_because_some_groups_match()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

## My whishlist

I would happily stay away from signals if there is a chance to solve this problem in the models `save()` method - but I'm stuck...

Comment: Maybe you have to try `django-model-utils`'s [field-tracker](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker)

Comment: Dear @martbln, I would like to stay away from external packages (and signals...) for this purpose , and I think ``FieldTracker`` from ``django-model-utils`` does not track m2m fields (https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/issues/163#issuecomment-78296098) anyway.

Comment: Great question.  I have this very same problem.  Any update?

Comment: I am facing the same problem but my question is why you do not like to use signals? it is not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

You asked after the dark magic.  Tell me, what are you willing to sacrifice to avoid using signals?  Would you embrace a greater evil?  What if I were to suggest that you could start a new thread and sleep for a few seconds until you thought that the m2m relations were *probably* saved before doing anything?

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# file: users/models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_something(obj):
        sleep(3)
        # stuff

    thread = Thread(target = do_something, args = [self], daemon=True)
    thread.start()
```